# Проблема с отправкой XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Разбираяюсь с API EWA (https://api.ewa.ua)
Столкнулся со следующей проблемой.

При отправке кросс доменного запроса получаю ошибку "Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin"
Пробовал различный варианты, прочитал все что только можно на различных ресурсах но проблема осталась.

Сам код:

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

let body = 'email=test@gmail.com&password=test',
    URL = 'https://web.ewa.ua/ewa/api/v7/user/login';

xhr.open('POST', URL, true);

xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.send(body);
```

Скрин консоли:
[image: Error]

Comment: значит не все прочитали) ошибка в том, что вам нельзя отправлять запрос с вашего домена на `web.ewa.ua`. Скорее всего запрос апи должен быть с сервера

Comment: Я понял) Находил еще такой пункт в доке "Произвести регистрацию собственного адреса. Это необходимо для того, чтобы при входе в систему по собственному адресу на форме логина отображался персональный логотип компании. Для регистрации компании company.ua (адрес взят для примера) необходимо в DNS-настройках домена company.ua добавить CNAME-запись ewa.company.ua со ссылкой на хост web.ewa.ua" , он имеет место быть? Или как мне лучше поступить? До этого я сделал все через Curl php, все работало но не сохраняло куки. Так что решил сделать через js.

Comment: попробуйте, по сути, сервер должен просто разрешить вам запросы к  нему. Для этого он должен знать ваше домен